# How to write data to Firebase Realtime DB in Google Cloud Function triggered by google.firebase.database.ref.v1.created event?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a cloud function in python which is being triggered on created data inside some key (e.g. tags)

[image]

My function starts like:

```
import os
import functions_framework
import numpy
import uuid

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def manage_tags(cloud_event):
   data = cloud_event.data

   [...]
```

I would like to know how can I insert, after all the logic done on that function, some data in a different DB key

Thank you in advance

I am aware of the firebase_admin package for python, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way (not need to re-init app, setting connection params, etc), since I am using cloud function and I already have the event information

Comment: Any clue on this? :(